# componentDidMount Fun issues

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code

```
  componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props && this.props.match && this.props.match.params.code) {
            console.dir("mount1");
            this._handleCode(this.props.match.params.code);
        } else {
            console.dir("mount2");
            this.setState({loading: false});
        }
    }
```

Why is mount2 being printed out then mount1 when the url parameter has a code in it? ex. /subscriptionGroup/test

```
 <ProtectedRoute path="/subscriptioncode/:code" component={SubscriptionCodeActivate}/>

const ProtectedRoute = ({
                                   path,
                                   component: Component,
                                   render,
                                   ...rest
                               }) => {
    return (
        <Route
            path={path}
            {...rest}
            render={props => {
                if (Utils.isAuthenticated()) {
                    return Component ? <Component {...props} /> : render(props);
                } else {
                    return <Redirect to={`/login?redirect=${props.location.pathname}`} />;
                }
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: How are you instantiating your component? i.e. can you show us what your routes look like?

Comment: see above @IsmaelPadilla

Comment: What is this  return Component ? <Component {...props} /> : render(props); ? Why don't you just return the Component, if isAuthenticated() returns true?